# getting JSON data into an angularJS service and comparing for login

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, http, foreach

I have a nodejs server setup. It is pulling data from my database and turning it into JSON to be pulled from my NodeJS server.

I have this service:

```
.service('LoginService', function ($q) {
   return {
      loginUser: function (name, pw) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          var promise = deferred.promise;

          if (name == 'user' && pw == 'secret') {
              deferred.resolve('Welcome ' + name + '!');
          } else {
              deferred.reject('Wrong credentials.');
          }
          promise.success = function (fn) {
              promise.then(fn);
              return promise;
          }
          promise.error = function (fn) {
              promise.then(null, fn);
              return promise;
          }
          return promise;
      }
   }
})
```

Now in this I am comparing the input by the user for password and username to `user` and `secret`. Now that I have some JSON data on my server I would like to iterate through that and compare it to `name` and `pw` in my service.

So I think its something like this but I think its a syntax error

```
$http.get("http://***.***.**.***:****/login").success(function(data) {
   $scope.user = data
});
angular.forEach(data, function(username, key) {
   if(name == $scope.username && pw == $scope.password) { 
     //login code from above
   }
});
```

My angularJS syntax is way off, I'm still learning. I'm not sure I'm even aloud to use `$scope` in a service.

So really what Im looking for is to iterate through my values in the JSON and compare them to the values entered by the user.

**Edit 1**

Here I will add More background to the project to help you understand what I am doing and why.

I have a google cloud SQL database that I have added records to with MySQL work bench. In the database there is a users table, this contains information like name, age gender, email, password etc. I have 2 records in this table.

I also have a google nodeJS server that I use to access the database records and return them as JSON from a web address (http://:/load).

This is why I would Like my login attempt to check the JSON array for the username and password. the password is unencrypted atm but I just want my basic functionality in there first that checks if the values are equal.

I hope this makes it more clear

Comment: Can you please explain more? Why you are making login comparison in angular (front-end) and not in nodejs (backend)?

Comment: I was following a tutorial for login with angular. But you're saying I should use node JS to login? Should I still use a login controller and service? Or is the validation comparason done purely in the nodeJS (Server.js) instance I have?

Comment: OK i understand your confusion, it's javascript everywhere! I will post an answer with an example below.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood something! You cant have real login validation in angularjs everyone could see the correct credentials in you client code, you should make some basic validations like the email is valid the password is long enough etc... Here is an example of basic login flow.

AngularJS -- Frontend (Anyone could see this code because is run on client browser)

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        if ($scope.username && $scope.password && $scope.password.length > 5) {
            //more validations could be made here, or best in a directive!

            //this could be a service.
            $http.post('http://myserver.com/login', {
                username: $scope.username,
                password: $scope.password
            }).sucess(function(data){
                alert('logged!')
            }).error(function(err){
                alert('not logged::'+err)
            })
        }
    }
})
```

NodeJS -- Backend (only you could see this code because is run on your server)

```
app.post('login', function(req, res){
  var username = req.param('username');
  var password = req.param('password');
  if(username=='myusername' && password=='mypassword') {
    //again of course this is a demo
    //in real world you use a DB!
    return res.send('Logged!');
  }
  return res.status(403).send('Username and password not valid!');
});
```

This is a very basic example made with angularjs - expressjs

**Edit 1 Based on question edit**

You have a MySQL database so you should query your login credentials and let MySQL check if a user with this credentials exists. Anyway i am not familiar with google cloud services but i am sure there is a way to run queries on your DB!

If again you want to stick with your original plan and get the whole DB in nodejs and loop throught it, i dont recommend it but you can do it like this.

```
var request = require('request'); //npm install request

app.post('login', function(req, res) {
    var username = req.param('username');
    var password = req.param('password');

    request('http://www.dataFromMySQL.com', function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            var result = data.filter(function each(r) {
                return username == r.username && password == r.password;
            });
            if (result.length > 0) return res.send('logged')
            else return res.status(403).send('Username and password not valid!');
        }
        return res.status(403).send('Couldnt get db data.');
    })
});
```

Comment: surely people can't see every result from the loop? but you do have a point this logic is better in here. But it doesn't solve my problem fully, you've just kind of moved it from the angular to nodejs, I still need to loop through my JSON array to compare the login details. How would I compare the password and username input to the JSON data I get from my http://<mynodejsip>:<port>/load. Thanks for the input btw :)

Comment: i cant understand why you have a json array with login data? how you get this data? you dont have a database? anyway looping in an array is simple i cant see the problem... please explain more to help you solve this problem!

Comment: yeah I have a database, What I'll do is add an edit outlining the way I have everything set up that might help clear things up a bit :)